# How to know laravel connect with Oracle oci8 and select statment write

Tags: laravel, oracle, oci8, yajra-datatable

Here is my Code in laravel with Oci8. i get this result

> oci8 statement resource @364

. does anyone know what is issue? how to connect and use select statement.

```
$users = oci_connect('LE2', 'LE2', '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.55.5)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)))');
        if (!$users) {
            dd("no coonection");

          }else{
            $ss = oci_parse($users, "SELECT * FROM v_doctor_list");
            dd($ss);
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use yajra library to connect laravel to oracle 
you can use this code to test connection

```
if (DB::connection('your-connection-name')->getDatabaseName()) {
    echo "connected" 
}else{
 echo "not connected" 
}
```